# Setting tls options issue

Tags: openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I get this error when attempting to test mosquitto with tls. I'm on windows so I may have the wrong command.

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 8883 -t test --tls-version tlsv1.1 --capath /mosquitto_client/ca_certificates/ca.crt.pem --insecure --cert /mosquitto_client/certs/garage.local.crt.pem --key /mosquitto_client/certs/garage.local.key.pem
```

Error: Problem setting TLS options.

Comment: You gotta give us more information about the problem. What is the error you get when trying to set the TLS params?

Comment: The error is as I said "Problem setting TLS options".

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.  I discovered that if I installed mosquitto_sub version 1.5.8 via `sudo snap install mosquitto` it would fail like this.  If I installed mosquitto_sub version 1.4.15 via `sudo apt install mosquitto-clients` it did not have this issue.  Not sure if the problem is the snap packaging or the newer version of mosquitto_sub, but thought I would share this information.